# Does Azure function pricing include webhooks too?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I understood how functions [pricing](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/calculator/#functions-1) works. It is basically the sum of request charges and computation charges. Assuming I use a **webhook + API** triiger for my function. Now how my pricing works ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regardless of the trigger type (HTTP/WebHook, Queue, Service Bus, etc.), the billing model (**from an Azure Functions' perspective**) is the same, so covered by the pricing page and the billing calculator you've linked to.

Any other resources external to Azure Functions (service bus, storage, services providing the WebHook) would have their own costs.

I hope this helps.